# How do i pass the R.id to a method?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have this class:

```
public class FlowerForYouWidget extends AppWidgetProvider

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
....
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.flower_widget);
buildClock(context, views, "R.id.widgetHour", curHour);
....
}

public static RemoteViews buildClock(Context context, RemoteViews views, String btnId, String currentValue)
{
....
views.setImageViewBitmap(btnId, myBitmap);
....
}
```

I need to pass the "R.id.widgetHour" to buildClock() method and to setImageViewBitmap as param.

Comment: Its an integer value.. Correct your params to accept an integer

Answer (score 5):

All references maintained by the R class are int's. Just pass it through as an int and you'll be able to use it within your function

Answer (score 3):

Those are integer constants, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

R class constants are integers, unique id's for components in your app's resources.
So pass it as an integer, then you can use it normally.

**OR** as you have it currently (a string) you can use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to get this id by the name.

But you don't even need to pass it; R class is fully static so you can access all of your id's from everywhere.